# why we need to make the size of our burst 2 times the product of bandwidth and delay?

Tags: network, bandwidth, transport-protocol, link-utilization

A textbook which says:

> The bandwidth-delay product defines the number of bits that can fill the link. This measurement is important if we need to send data in bursts and wait for the acknowledgment of each burst before sending the next one. To use the maximum capability of the link, we need to make the size of our burst 2 times the product of bandwidth and delay

I'm a little bit confused, let's say we have an example as the picture shows below:

[image: example]

So according to what the textbook says, I need to send a burst of data of 50 bits, I understand it is a waste of bandwidth to send a burst of data that is less than 25 bits, but what's the difference if I send the burst of data of 100 bits, 200 bits ... etc?

Comment: From my point of view, it is only example for learning how it works, no any connection to real speeds/protocols (I would say, implementations of protocols). It is just example of approach, and amount of bits will be changed according to delay and bandwidth of your link/technology. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please do not cross-post a question on multiple SE sites. Pick one site and delete the question on the other sites, otherwise you may find the question closed on all the sites for cross-posting.

Comment: @Zac67 looks like this question was asked last year, but only resurrected because somebody edited it, and then in May, the same question was asked again, in https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/67949/why-we-make-each-burst-of-data-2-times-the-product-of-bandwidth-and-delay